# WebView evaluateJavascript behaving unpredictably

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I've tried to trigger a JavaScript function from my Android code in a WebView unsuccessfully. (I've removed all clutter for this example but eventually it'll need to be a WebView, so no AndroidJSCore)

From what I gather if I just want one way execution (my Java code executing JavaScript code) I have no need for a JavaScriptInterface so I've setup my WebView like this:

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage consoleMessage) {
            Log.d("Console output", consoleMessage.message());
            return super.onConsoleMessage(consoleMessage);
        }
    });
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                webView.evaluateJavascript("test();", null);
            } else {
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:test();");
            }
        }
    });
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Which means that when the page has loaded it should trigger the *test* function in JavaScript.

And here's where it loses me. I tried with 3 different *test* functions and none behave like I'd expect them to.

I load them from a string resource wrapped in CDATA like this:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", getResources().getString(R.string.test_html),
            "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8", null);
```

**Version 1, single quotes 'test'**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function test(){
            console.log('test');
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Logcat output:

> D/Console output: Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined

**Version 2, double quotes "test"**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function test(){
            console.log("test");
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Logcat output:

> D/Console output: function test(){ console.log(test); }

**Version 3, double quotes "testme"**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function test(){
            console.log("testme");
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Logcat output:

> D/Console output: Uncaught ReferenceError: testme is not defined

This last one in particular is very odd to me, why would "testme" need to be defined? It's just what I want to send to the log?

Any ideas as to why it does this and how to execute JavaScript correctly from Android? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, so after banging my head against this for some more time I've found out why it doesn't work after some trial and error.

I have no idea why but even if encapsulated in CDATA wrappers *loadDataWithBaseURL* does not like single or double quotes, anywhere in its second parameter.

So, **this does not work**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function test(){
            console.log("test");
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

But **this does work**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
        function test(){
            console.log(\"test\");
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Of course when creating the string in Java the editor will show you need to escape the double quotes, but when creating it as a resource, wrapping it in CDATA and then loading it at no point does it give a heads up.

So, hope this is useful to someone, someday.